# why Travis does not trigger builds of local merged commits when pushed?

Tags: node.js, angular, github, continuous-integration, commit

I develop my Project in "Develop" that is a local branch(it is not pushed to remote repository),
when i finish a featuring i merge it in the master branch ,but when i push the merged commit(Master) Travis builds just the merged commit (the last commit) 
and  when he finishes the build i cannot see my changes on the prod version that is deployed,but in local i can see my changes. 
The image below shows that the features commited on develop branch are not build in Travis,can someone helps me figure out how to solve this issue.Thank's a loot.

[image: these are the commits]

this is .travis.yml file :

[image]

Comment: show us your `.travis.yml` and also what your settings are on the webhook

Comment: i just add the travis yaml file,before adding the "develop" branch ,when Travis builds it deploys my changes and i can see my changes

Comment: what about your webhooks...